# Box API to simulate the event of item_preview

Tags: python, box, boxapiv2

I need an help with the Box API.

I am trying to generate an event of item preview using python for my box app. I am currently able to capture all the item preview events using the long polling way, `client.events().generate_events_with_long_polling(stream_position=None)`. This will return me the generator from which I use `next()` to get all the events of item preview.

But my query is how to create an event of `item_preview` itself programatically without the GUI, so that the I can cause the event of `item_preview` and capture the same from the python scripts itself, without the use of browser.

Basically I need a box API in Python using which I can simulate the event of `item_preview`.